# Local Jekyll serve different from actual output

Tags: css, jekyll, favicon

I have an issue with discrepancy between local Jekyll serve and actual output.

[image: Screenshot of live website tab without favicon]

First picture is actual output. Favicon doesn't show up properly on site.

[image: Screenshot of local website tab with favicon]

Second picture is local jekyll serve. It shows my favicon properly.

I already tried someone else's answer which is changing _config.yml like following explanation.

The answer said fix this code.
`url: "http://flash-kim142.github.io"`
to
`url: "https://flash-kim142.github.io"`

Currently my `favicon.png`'s location is `/Desktop/Documents/Github/My Blog/assets`

Should I change this location or have to try something else?

Answer (score 0):

Your `favicon` URL should be relative to your file, so use `assets/<filename>.<extension>`. Don't include the whole hard-code path like `Desktop/Documents/...`.

This is your generated code on your home page:

```html
<!-- For all browsers -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/main.css">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico">
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/Documents/GitHub/My Blog/apple-touch-icon.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/Documents/GitHub/My Blog/favicon-32x32.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/Documents/GitHub/My Blog/favicon-16x16.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/Documents/GitHub/My Blog/assets/favicon.png">
<link rel="mask-icon" href="/Documents/GitHub/My Blog/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#5bbad5">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/Documents/GitHub/My Blog/favicon.ico">
<meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#da532c">
<meta name="msapplication-config" content="/Documents/GitHub/My Blog/browserconfig.xml">
<meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
<link href="/assets/favicon.png/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon"/>
```

But it should be like this:

```html
<!-- For all browsers -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/css/main.css">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="./favicon.ico">
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="./favicon.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="./apple-touch-icon.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="./favicon-32x32.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="./favicon-16x16.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="./assets/favicon.png">
<link rel="mask-icon" href="./safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#5bbad5">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="./favicon.ico">
<meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#da532c">
<meta name="msapplication-config" content="./browserconfig.xml">
<meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
<link href="/assets/favicon.png/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon"/>
```

Comment: Thank u soooo much!! It finally worked!!

Then the problem was about my head.html? 
Cuz I also changed my asset_url in _config.yml
from ```"/assets/favicon.png"```  to ```"/assets/<favicon.png>.<extension>"```

Or both of them have to work at the same time so it can fix my favicon problem?

Comment: No need to add `/assets/<favicon.png>.<extension>`!! That was an example for you! you can simply right `assets/favicon.png`

Comment: @Flash-KIM142 You are also not using `site.asset_url` in your template, so there is no effect from the `_config.yml` file at all.

Comment: Oh.. thanks again lol 
I still have a far far way to go to get this whole jekyll thing... I deleted asset.url from _config.yml 
really appericiate big time!